# I want to verify that the 'questionId' is a number. How to verify it using groovy script?

Tags: testing, groovy, soapui, web-api-testing, jsonresponse

Part of json object as below, need to extract `questionId` and check whether it is number:

```
{
    "rootProductQuestionId": "17",
    "questionAnswers": [ 
        {
            "question": "",
            "questionId": "17",
            "answer": ""
        }
    ],

    "productId": "8",
    "notes": ""
}
```

Comment: You have the questionId in your JSON, why you want to verify that? edit your question and explain well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an option for isNumber() check, something like:

```
import groovy.json.jsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText('{"rootProductQuestionId":"17","questionAnswers":[{"question":"","questionId":"17","answer":""}],"productId":"8","notes":""}')
return json.questionAnswers.questionId[0].isNumber()
```

Comment: Are you sure that, he want JSON parsing?  the question is not clear, hope so.

Comment: @NitinDhomse, what issue do you see?